# jquery show and hide functionality not worked

Tags: jquery

I have a set of records with an "edit" button next to them.
I also have a div that has a form inside of it.

when I click on "edit" I show the div. Inside the div, I have a "close" button which simply closes the div via jquery.hide(). when I then click the "edit" button for another record, the div does not get displayed at all.

I use other shows and hide within my code for other elements and they work quite fine. Only this one I can't get working.

Is there a specific usage of the show() and hide() methods in my case?

```
$('.edit').live('click', function () {
    var theid = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#' + theid).empty().append($('.rec_edit').show());

    if ($('#txt_nowediting_id').val() > 0) {
        load_single_rec($('#txt_nowediting_id').val());
    };

    $('#txt_nowediting_id').val(theid);
    return false;
});

$('#btnCancelEdit').click(function () {
    $('.rec_edit').hide();
    load_single_rec($('#txt_nowediting_id').val());
    return false;
});
```

here .rec_edit is the div that gets hidden and shown...

Comment: It seems like you are doing something wrong, but we can hardly guess your code and point out the error. Maybe you could show the relevant part for the "edit" button.

Comment: Not much else that can be added without looking at the code.  A couple things that may be going wrong.... 

 1. The click listener is only being applied to one "edit" element to begin with and you  happen to be clicking that first.
 2. The edit's are getting regenerated somehow so that after the initial click, they no longer have the click listener bound.
 3. The div that is shown/hidden is modified somehow so when the click listener attempts to reference it, it can no longer find it in the dom.

Post some code and hopefully you'll get some more specific feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: in your `#btnCancelEdit` click handler, change this:

```
$('.rec_edit').hide();
```

to this:

```
$('.rec_edit').hide().appendTo('body');
```

(Or wherever it originally is in markup, if not `body`.) Otherwise I think your call to `empty()` when setting up the editor is wiping it out.

Here's a full example that works for me (tweaked code to get around incomplete code, e.g. `load_single_rec`):

```
<html>
    <head>

        <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-1.3.2.js'></script>

        <script type='text/javascript'>
            var editor;

            $(document).ready(function() {

                $('.edit').live('click', function() {
                    var theid = $(this).attr('id');

                    $('#' + theid).empty().append($('.rec_edit').show());
    /*
                    if ($('#txt_nowediting_id').val() > 0) {
                        load_single_rec($('#txt_nowediting_id').val());
                    };
    */
                    $('#txt_nowediting_id').val(theid);

                    return false;
                });


                $('#btnCancelEdit').click(function() {
                    $('.rec_edit').hide().appendTo('body');

                    // load_single_rec($('#txt_nowediting_id').val());
                    $('#' + $('#txt_nowediting_id').val()).text('edited!');
                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <form>

            <div id='div1' class='edit' style='border: 2px solid #00f;' >
                Edit me
            </div>

            <div id='div2' class='edit' style='border: 2px solid #00f;' >
                Edit me too
            </div>

            <div class='rec_edit' style='display:none; border: 2px solid #f00;'>
                Editor
                <input type='button' id='btnCancelEdit' value='Cancel' />
            </div>

            <input type='hidden' id='txt_nowediting_id' />


        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I updated your code slightly, and it works slightly better: http://jsbin.com/uniga (At http://jsbin.com/uniga/edit you can see and edit the code)

Comment: you were indeed right about appending to body after calling empty... thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I tried to keep myself close to your original idea. 
I don't think it's a good idea to make the parent div a clickable zone to edit the contents.

You should add "edit" text links so the user doesn't mis click the div leading to undesired results.

## The problem

The problem you had was the [append](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/append) itself. You need to create a "new" entity on the DOM to allow jQuery to deal with it. Also I fixed the "Cancel Edit" so that when you cancel it loops through the whole editable divs to hide the editable box AND restore the original data.

## Second version that'll allow only 1 edit using a reference of an existent div.

Full code [here](http://stackoverflow.pastebin.com/m3806e092)

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var content = $('.rec_edit').html();
    var editing = false;
$('.edit').click(function() {
        if( editing == false ) {
            var theid = $(this).attr('id');
            var tis = "#"+theid;
            // We hide P, because it's the original, so when we hide the "editing" div
            // the original pops back in.
            $(tis + " p").hide("fast");
            // 
            $(tis).append( $('.rec_edit').show().html(content + theid) );
            editing = true;
        }
    return false;
});
$('#btnCancelEdit').click(function() {
    $('.rec_edit').each(function(){
        if( editing == true ) {
            // We get the parent id, so we can use it to display the hidden P to
            // restore the original.
            var parent = "#" + $(this).parent().get(0).id + " p";
            $(parent).show("fast");
            $(this).hide();
            editing = false;
            // $(this).remove();
        }
        });

    return false;
});
    });
```

Comment: thanks for the effort. It's not logical for me to re-create the div each time as its content is quite large. Instead I wish to hide/show it.

the div is actually resides below the page independent of any of the elements that has the "edit" link by their side. 

my problem is when I call hide() the div gets removed from the DOM. I only want to hide it. I tried css('visibility', 'hidden') but no luck.

Can it be that my edits are generated on the fly and I use the .live method to bind click event (as also seen from the code) ?

Comment: That's weird. Hide is not supposed to remove it from the DOM. Emin, it would be easier for everyone if you can provide your whole code, including the HTML.

Comment: @Rendell Benavidez: I second that.

Comment: @Emin : can the editable box appear more than one at the same time?